# Muting a hidden Youtube iframe .. button onclick in JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

I am making a fun little website with a video and music. I made the video in iMovie and then put in on youtube. In the past when I have worked with iMovie, it makes you purchase music before adding it to the video. I thought I would get around this by including two iframes in my html- one for the music from youtube and one for the iMovie. I have them both on autoplay when the site loads, and the music iframe is hidden. Since it is hidden, I cannot see the volume controls.

I want an option to mute the music, so thought I would add a button in the html, and do an `onclick` (and a function in JS) but I can't get anything to work. the code is below. any advice? I've tried many, many things. thanks!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AKO</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left"></span>AKO<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></h1><h2 style="font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; border-width: 0px;">Scooter</h2>
        <button id="muteButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off" onclick="myFunction()" style="float:right;"></button>
    </header>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <div align="center">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" align="middle" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bYjb5Lqdktk?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=bYjb5Lqdktk" frameBorder="0" seamless="seamless" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br />
    <div id="bottomDiv">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span id="title" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">
                <br>
                SPORTS
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="color: gray;">
                Scooter
                <br>
                Skate
                <br>
                Surf
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span id="title" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">
                <br>
                AKO
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="color: gray;">
                About
                <br>
                Athletes
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span id="title" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">
                <br>
                CONTACT
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="color: gray;">
                Email <span style="color: #16B7A2">kmorrical@AKOScoot.com</span>
                <br>
                Phone <span style="color: #16B7A2">1-800-999-9999</span>
                <br>
                Location <span style="color: #16B7A2">OB, SD, CA</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="janesMusic" width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/beWnAmN1y3o?start=32&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
alert("hi!");

var music = document.getElementById('janesMusic');
var button = document.getElementById('muteButton');

function myFunction() {
    var media = document.getElementById('janesMusic');
    media.volume = 0; /*set volume to zero|takes values btw 0-1*/
    media.pause(); /*pause the audio/video*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Legal**

Had a bit of research for a moment and found out that what you want to do (hidden YouTube Player, only play the audio part...) would be against the terms of service of the YouTube API.

You can find them in the *I. Additional Prohibitions* part of the YouTube API [Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies?hl=it).

> 7. separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available as part of, or in connection with, YouTube API Services. For example, you must not apply alternate audio tracks to videos;
> 8. promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available as part of, or in connection with, the YouTube API Services;
> 9. create, include, or promote features that play content, including audio or video components, from a background player, meaning a player that is not displayed in the page, tab, or screen that the user is viewing;

You could also look here: [Webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44071/can-i-hide-an-embedded-youtube-video-or-is-that-against-the-terms-of-use)

---

**Example**

When I tried to show the video in a smaller player. This (self-explaining message) showed up in the following screenshot:

[image: Restricted YouTube Video is restricted]

You could probably work around this, but I can definitely **not** recommend this.

---

**What you could do**

Now, if I were you, I'd get the music from another source. Cause it's against their terms of service and it would be immensely inefficient to stream the video just for the audio part.

I would just place an audio file in the same workspace and get it from there.

```
<audio id="music" controls>
  <source src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Then you should be able to mute your audio content with `XXX.muted = true`.
It's the same for audio and video content.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("music");
audio.muted = true; //audio.muted = false; to unmute
```

Recommended to read: [W3Schools HTML5 Audio](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

I'm sorry I couldn't help you with your initial question but I hope this helps.

Comment: @CodingK8 Hope I could help :)